# unable to get response from an api

Tags: api, request, postman

I a requesting an API to get response but it gives below some "JWT_TOKEN_MiSSING" response:

```
{
"response": {
    "ids": "",
    "time": 1505890122982,
    "error": "JWT_TOKEN_MISSING",
    "status": "failure"
    }
}
```

API is: "https://www.viu.com/api/container/load?appid=viu_desktop&iid=9fa3fec0-9457-11e7-bee5-ed8c9b3d7f48&regionid=all&ver=1.0&aver=5.0&fmt=json&contentCountry=in&contentFlavour=telugu&languageid=en&platform=desktop&vuserid=viu-guest-9fa3fec0-9457-11e7-bee5-ed8c9b3d7f48&userid=guest-9fa3fec0-9457-11e7-bee5-ed8c9b3d7f48&ccode=IN&geo=2&id=playlist-24926470&start=0&limit=20&geofiltered=false"

I tried passing all the headers but no luck.

Comment: I don't see any token in your request

Comment: "https://www.viu.com/in-telugu/en/tag-social_ep_3_out_now-playlist-24926470"
This is the url when went to this url on chrome browser then on Network tab, there are lots of Headers response, I tried to pass them all, but no luck. Is there any other way to see what headers are missing

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this API use JWT TOKEN or other tokens (such as HTTP BASIC AUTHENTICATION) to authenticate, you need to know this and add it to your request headers.

Comment: "https://www.viu.com/in-telugu/en/tag-social_ep_3_out_now-playlist-24926470"
This is the url, when I went to this url on chrome browser then on Network tab, there are lots of Headers response, I tried to pass them all, but no luck. Is there any other way to see what headers are missing

Comment: @michael Sorry I just saw a viu 404 page, and headers I found there seems no help. I think the token may be a pre-defined code between server and client which cannot be acknowledged if you are 3rd party. You can have a look at on OAuth 2 or other authentication protocol for help.

Comment: this is the website "https://www.viu.com/ott/in/telugu-en/tag-spotlight-playlist-24435059"
I want to crawl and get all the details of this url. Please help